# Selenium navigate without getting logged out

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What I want to do is follow one Instagram account in Chrome, incognito mode. The problem is that after I log in successfully, the driver gets the account's link(when the follow function is called) and I am no longer logged in.

I did the same operations without the automated driver and there is no problem.

Here are my 2 functions:

```
def login(driver):
    # Auto log in to instagram
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
    # Wait until the screen has loaded
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_ph6vk"))
            )
    except Exception:
        print("Accounts page timed out")
    input_elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_ph6vk")

    input_elem[0].send_keys("username")
    input_elem[1].send_keys("password")
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_qv64e")
    login_button.click()

def follow(driver, account_to_follow_link):

    driver.get(account_to_follow_link)

    #driver.close()
```

And here is my driver instantiation and its options:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")


# Path of current driver & instantiation of driver object
os.chdir(r'C:\ig_automation')
driver = os.getcwd() +"\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, 
executable_path=driver)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround. Instead of first logging into Instagram, I used this action order:

- opened the link to the account I wanted to follow
- clicked on the follow button -> it redirects the browser to the login page
- log in -> automatically redirects the browser to the account I wanted to follow(without logging out)
- click follow button

That's it - this workaround works in my case as I just want to do one action, but if you want to do more, you should consider another solution

Answer (score 0):

The `driver.get(account_to_follow_link)` causes selenium to navigate away from the page you just logged into, effectively logging you out. You can't use `driver.get()`.

What will be more successful is finding an element on the page that is loaded by the server after login is successful, and switching to an element or context that is already loaded by the page. This means using a `driver.switch_to...()` probably.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder, though, if there is any other way. If I log in without automation it remains logged in when I get the new link, so there must be some option for the chrome driver to keep that data.

Comment: I believe that is because you perform a click on a link as a user, or the website automatically renders a new page after successful login. That is why I recommended `driver.switch_to...()`. This acquires a handle to the new content that is automatically created by the website. Then you're free to find and click the link element. This is standard automation for many login sites. This enables website authors to hide the (member) content until the login operation is successful.

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting and I agree with you, though I found an easier way, but it only works on the problem I am trying to solve. As I need the program to follow only one account/session(once in 20-30 min) it's easier to just click follow, (it automatically redirects me to login page) then login (then it redirects me back to the account I wanted to follow) and click follow. I know the solution is a little bit bad because if I had a large number of accounts it would require to log in multiple times, but for only one, I guess that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't log me out if I issue more get requests from the same scope, the same method or within the same object(if you make a class that implements the driver). This preserves the driver cookies. You can make a class with driver declared in the global scope or pass `driver.get_cookies()` to preserve site cookies, and to keep yourself logged in.

UNCONFIRMED:
This may possibly also be accomplished by simply declaring the driver in the global scope of your python program.